# How to call function in macvim

Tags: java, vim, macvim

I am new to macvim. I installed macvim with Janus. I try to compile and run the java file. To do this I tried to write a function to gather all those commands in .gvimrc file. However when I run it in command mode, it said "E492: not an editor command". Please tell me how to realize such purpose. 
The code in .gvimrc is

```
" define a java compile and run function
function! s:RunJava(var1)
  let str1=a:var1
  shell
  javac  str1.java
  java   str1
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 RunJava call s:RunJava(<f-args>)
```

and in command mode I input ":RunJava filename"

Answer (score 5):

A more vim like way of doing this would be to use `:make`.

### :make

- Set your compiler via `:compiler javac`.
- Probably best to add it to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/java.vim`
- Execute `:make foo.java`. This is the same as `javac foo.java`
- `:make %` to make the current file
- `:make` will populate the quickfix list with any errors.

### Quickfix list

- Use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to move between your errors.
- `:copen` to open up the quickfix list in a window (`:cclose` to close)
- `:cwindow` to open quickfix list window only if there are errors
- May want to use better mappings for `:cnext` and friends. I suggest Tim Pope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin

### Run the build

Sadly Vim has no native way to run the build however you do have options:

- use `:!` to run the build. e.g. `:!java foo` or `:!java %<`
- use `system()`. e.g. `let output = system('java ' . shellescape(filename))`
- Open a new buffer and read in stdout. e.g. `:r !java foo`
- Suspend vim via `<c-z>` and run `java foo`

### All together

If you want to do this all as one command you can can make special function and command.

```
function! s:RunJava(fname)
  compiler javac
  execute 'make ' . a:fname
  cwindow
  if getqflist() == []
    execute '!java ' . fnamemodify(a:fname, ':r')
  endif
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -complete=file RunJava call s:RunJava(expand(<f-args>))
```

This will `:make` the file then if there are no errors it will run the build via `:!java`

For more help see:

```
:h :make
:h :compiler
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :copen
:h :cwindow
:h :!
:h system(
:h :r!
```

Comment: Your comments are excellent. I then put this function in .gvimrc and try to run it, but nothing occurred. If it is correct to put this function in .gvimrc, what is the command to call it?

Comment: Silly me I forgot to name my command. It is called `RunJava`. This is really only a jumping off point. I am sure there may be a need to change the working directory or possibly convert slashes to dots.

Comment: I run it by |:!RunJava filename|, but they said "/bin/bash: RunJava: command not found". I put the function in .gvimrc and .vimrc. Any advice?

Comment: 1) make sure you copy the latest snippet and put it in your `~/.vimrc` file. 2) Run it from via via `:RunJava foo.java` where foo.java is your filename. It uses file completion to make things easier. It looks like you where running `!RunJava` which is wrong (no `!`)

Comment: 1) I directly copy your latest function to .vimrc; so I think it should have latest snippet; 2) I delete ! then run it; but it's back to the previous error: "E492: not an editor command: RunJava foo.java".  For macvim, I directly unzip the package from vim google group, and for Janus, I run "$ curl -Lo- http://bit.ly/janus-bootstrap | bash" . Also from Janus, it requires to put all configuration setting in .gvimrc (https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/FAQ), and actually I put your function in both files. Still nothing works.

Comment: I have tried this in my own vimrc and with a spartan `~/.vimrc` and it works fine. I can only assume janus is doing something odd. My next suggestion is to save the snippet in to some other file, e.g. `~/RunJava.vim`, and then source it directly, e.g. `:source ~/RunJava.vim`. This should source the command and it should be available. Now you can go and run the command. I know this may sound odd but vim distributions are considered harmful because they interrupt the vim journey and they cause issues with customization.

Comment: `s:RunJava` is local script function you can call it from same script in your case - from .(g)vimrc. For manual call you must define function like this `g:RunJava`. `g:` for global functions and variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
function! s:RunJava(var1)
  let str1=a:var1
  exec '!javac '.str1.'java'
  if !v:shell_error
    exec '!java '.str1
  endif
endfunction
```

or

```
function! s:RunJava(var1)
  let str1=a:var1
  let consoleOutput = system('javac', str1.'java')
  "here you can use the output if you like
  if !v:shell_error
      exec '!java '.str1
  endif
endfunction
```

all codes were not tested